# Android google maps trouble on markers remove

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am implementing Android Google Maps v2. And adding to map several markerks, after removing markers located beyond the screen boundaries some markers icons lost image
[Marker icons after removing other markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OdPZ.png)
If using maker.setVisible(false) that everything is fine

Code where calling marker.remove()

`List<Point> points = ((SearchPointsMapResponse) response).getPoints();
            Iterator<Point> iterator;
            for (iterator = mPoints.values().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Point point = iterator.next();
                if (!points.contains(point)) {
                    Marker marker = mMarkers.remove(point.getId());
                    marker.remove();
                    iterator.remove();
                }
}`

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: @Nisarg i`m posted code to question

Comment: What is mMarkers ? how do you set points ids ?

Comment: @Smartiz mMarkers is a 
`private Map<String, Marker> mMarkers = new HashMap<>(); private Map<Marker, Point> mPoints = new HashMap<>();`
where String key is a Point.getId(). 

All code for adding markers/points on map
http://imgur.com/BKSaio2
http://imgur.com/yLfnh1m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i guess is that the problem is in this part :

```
 Marker marker = mMarkers.remove(point.getId());
 marker.remove();
 iterator.remove();
```

> mMarkers.remove(int);

will remove the object in that particular position! not the object with that id !
lets have an example:

we have a point with id of 3. Calling `mMarkers.remove(3);` will remove the 4th added marker! not the marker with id of 3 !

Comment: Ty for you answer, but mMarkers.remove calling with key - mMarkers.remove(Object key) because Point.getId() - returns the point id with String type.